# Recive JS object and fetch data from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Angular in frontend and I am trying to send object such as:

```
obj = {
  "foo" : "1",
  "bar" : 2,
  "baz" : 3
}
```

And when Rails recives this object, it should send back data from database depending on these parameters. This is my current method to create API:

```
  def index
    @tickets = Ticket.select(
      'id',
      'departure_date',
      'departure_country',
      'departure_country_tag'
    )
    render status:200, json: { tickets: @tickets}
  end
```

However this fetches all data from database. I only want to fetch data that matches parameters from the object.

Any suggestion on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select allows you to specify the attributes to be returned. You need to add a clause to that query with the values from the front end.

```
@tickets = Ticket.select(
  'id',
  'departure_date',
  'departure_country',
  'departure_country_tag'
).where(foo: obj["foo"], bar: obj["bar"], baz: obj["baz"])
```

If you look in the console you'll see how the data is being passed and you can amend the active record query accordingly.